# How to extract all variable names from json?

Tags: java, json

I need an array of variable names from JSON.
For example, if I receive

```
{
  "Java": 20526,
  "Shell": 292,
  "Groovy": 213
}
```

I want to map it to

```
String[] {"Java", "Shell", "Groovy"}
```

How can I do that effectively? Can I use Jackson?

Comment: you can map your json to a map, and then extract keySet from it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Map an array of JSON objects to a java.util.Map and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33914460/map-an-array-of-json-objects-to-a-java-util-map-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Jackson` to parse to an `HashMap<String, Object>` and then get the keys of your HashMap (if you intend to get all keys of the first level of course).

To get keys from all levels, you can create a recusive function which when the value of the key is another `HashMap` you extract it again.

Answer (score 1):

Convert json to map and get the keys. Below is the code. I have used GSON library.

```
String json = "{\"Java\": 20526,\"Shell\": 292,\"Groovy\": 213}";
Map map = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, Integer>>() {
        }.getType());
System.out.println(map.keySet());
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner using Gson 2.8.6:

```java
String json = "{\"Java\":20526,\"Shell\":292,\"Groovy\":213}";
String[] keys = JsonParser.parseString(json).getAsJsonObject().keySet().toArray(new String[0]);
```

Parse the JSON string to a `JsonObject`, get the key set and convert it to an array.